# Is there a disconnect method for custom wallet buttons?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, walletadapter

Using the Wallet Adapter package to add a custom connect/disconnect button and having some issues finding a way to disconnect a wallet. Connecting works find with useWalletModal() but can't seem to find any method to disconnect. Here's what I'm working with:

```
import { useWalletModal } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";

 const Nav = () => {

   const { setVisible } = useWalletModal();
   const { connected, userWallet, publicKey, connecting } = useWallet();

    const connectWallet = () => {
      setVisible(true)
    };

    const disconnectWallet = () => {
      // ????
    };

return ( 
   {connected ? (
                 <NavItem
                 label="Disconnect Wallet"
                 icon="disconnect"
                 onClick={disconnectWallet}
                 />
            ) : (
                <NavItem
                label="Connect Wallet"
                icon="wallet"
                onClick={connectWallet}
                />
            )}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a disconnect method on useWallet.

console.log(useWallet());

```
{
  autoConnect: false,
  wallets: [ { adapter: [PhantomWalletAdapter], readyState: 'Unsupported' } ],
  wallet: null,
  publicKey: null,
  connected: false,
  connecting: false,
  disconnecting: false,
  select: [Function: bound dispatchAction],
  connect: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  disconnect: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  sendTransaction: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
  signTransaction: undefined,
  signAllTransactions: undefined,
  signMessage: undefined
}
```

I did a quick test of the following and seemed to work fine to disconnect the wallet (for me at least...)

```
const { disconnect } = useWallet();

const disconnectWallet = () => {
   disconnect();
};
< ... >

<button onClick={() => disconnectWallet()}>Disconnect Wallet</button>
```

You can also use

```
import {
  WalletDisconnectButton
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";

<WalletDisconnectButton />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not "disconnect" request. (Metamask does not have either). to hack around, you define a state with `useState`:

```
const [connectedWallet,setConnectedWallet]=useState(false)
```

then if you are connected, set `connectedWallet`

```
const { connected, userWallet, publicKey, connecting } = useWallet();

if(connected){
   setConnectedWallet(true)
}
```

Now your top-level state value should be `connectedWallet`. If you are connected to the wallet, show UI based on `connectedWallet`. If you want to simulate the disconnect, just call

```
   setConnectedWallet(false)
```

since you want a clickable button

```
<button onClick={()=>setConnectedWallet(false)} />
```

Your app will behave like you are not connected to the wallet